# Transform property don't applying to CALayer

Tags: ios, calayer, catransform3d

I try to add 60 copies of my Dot object to layer, each of this objects must have its transform property (to form the circle). But for some reason transform property don't applying to layers. And all of the dot instances placed on the same place (12 o'clock). 
   This is my code:

```
- (void)addDots {
    CGFloat angle = (2*M_PI) / 60;

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        CALayer *layerDot = [self addDotWithSize:7 andColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        layerDot.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(i*angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        [self.layer addSublayer:layerDot];
    }
}


- (CALayer *)addDotWithSize:(float)size andColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CALayer *dotLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    dotLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size, size);
    dotLayer.position = CGPointMake(rectMain.size.width/2, 20);
    dotLayer.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;
    dotLayer.cornerRadius = size/2;
    dotLayer.masksToBounds = YES;

    return dotLayer;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Really some sort of dumb question ). The point is - right before it I did what I want now with CAReplicatorLayer and its property `instanceTransform` set to `CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` - did the trick. For some sake I tried the same with layer.transfom... I think I need to rest.

**UPDATE 2**

To accommodate dots in circle form you need to do next (hope this'll be helpful for somebody):

```
- (void)addDots {
    CGFloat angle = (2*M_PI) / 60;
    CGFloat angle90Offset = ((90) / 180.0 * M_PI);

    float x0 = CGRectGetMidX(rectMain);
    float y0 = CGRectGetMidY(rectMain);

    float radius = rectMain.size.width/2 - 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        CALayer *layerDot2 = [self addDotWithSize:size andColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        layerDot2.position = CGPointMake(x0 + cos(angle*i - angle90Offset) * radius, y0 + sin(angle*i - angle90Offset) * radius);
        [self.layer addSublayer:layerDot2];
    }
}
```

Comment: did you import quart/core framework..

Comment: @KishoreKumar: If he hadn't imported QuartzCore, he'd get a compiler error.

Comment: well, all dots are added at the same location as your code pretty clearly states, and then you rotate each dot around its center. Why should that change the location? You are simply missing the correct displacement or specifying a correct anchor-point for the rotation to make any visible impact.

Comment: You are setting the position in `addDotWithSize`, so won't changing the transform just rotate the layer (which you won't notice if it's a dot)?

Answer (score 0):

You're applying a rotation transform to a circular layer, where the anchor point (about which the rotation happens) is in the centre of that layer. You're not going to see any effect from that transform.

I *think* (it's pretty hard to do these in your head, and it's been a while since I've done one of these) you need to change the anchor point of the layer to be `CGPointMake(0.5,y)` where y is the distance from the centre of your dot to the centre of the clock, in units of the size of the dot. The rotation will then take place around that point, which should put your dots in the right position.